# Portable Display doesn't work anymore

Tags: laptop, external-display, portable

My USB portable monitor will not work since I installed the hard drive onto an HP laptop. I have installed all the new hardware drivers and do not have any more device issues in device manager view.  My old laptop was a lenovo. The new one is an HP. The system seems to recognize devices that I connect via, usb but the portable display still does not show anything on the screen.

It is probably a conflict in the registry but I'm not sure how to find it and the Power User does not have the luxury of letting me troubleshoot for hours to isolate the problem.

Comment: What OS do the two computers have?  Have you tried installing drivers from the manufacturer of the USB display?

Answer (score 0):

your description is a tad lacking. "i installed the hdd onto an hp" If you phisically moved the drive from one pc to another or ghosted from the old to the new and added drivers afterwords messy things like this are common.

if its windows there are a few apps out there that let you nuke all the information related to usb devices.  I dont remember what they are called off hand.  it could also be a windows profile issue where it didnt complete installing the drivers the first time and are now mucked up try plugging it in when you are logged in as another admin user.  It is not unusual for things like this to cause a reimage of a pc inorder to get them working right.
uninstall the usb drivers and reinstall them to see if that helps or update/down grade the usb drivers for the systemboard.  Does it matter which port its plugged in to and or if a powered hub lets it work right?

nix's should just work.  if it is a special driver that needs loading you may need to manually load it and or set up module loading rules.